# How to use qaf on Android chrome

Tags: qaf

I use below xml to run the test case, it always get exception on this step:

DeviceUtils.getQAFDriver().get("https://www.google.com");

**Exception:**: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error attempting to start URI. Original error: Error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'D:\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://www.baidu.com com.android.chrome' timed out after 20000ms'. Try to increase the 20000ms adb execution timeout represented by 'adbExecTimeout' capability

---

````
        <parameter name="driver.capabilities.deviceName" value="emulator-5554"/>
        <parameter name="driver.capabilities.automationName" value="UiAutomator2"/>
        <parameter name="driver.capabilities.appPackage" value="com.android.chrome"/>
        <parameter name="driver.capabilities.appActivity" value="com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main"/>
        <parameter name="driver.capabilities.noReset" value="true"/>
        <parameter name="appium.capabilities.driverClass" value="io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver"/>```
````

Comment: From the error it looks appium error in starting emulator.

Comment: But the Android chrome app is launched and the website also opened.
And in my another project, I launched an app, it can be operated correctly, then when I open a link from this app, it's open in android chrome, it's also work well.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Android mobile web automation](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/mobile-web/#android-mobile-web-automation) and set capabilities for browser automation instead of considering chrome native app. Alernate is after opening chrome as native app switch to webview and then try `driver.get()` but it is not recommend.

Comment: Solved，I fell into the wrong mindset, this exception is caused by that I use the Android Chrome as a desktop Chrome, so I use the driver.get to visit the website. Just control the Android Chrome as a normal android app, enter the website in the search input, then all goes well.